# For loop does not functioning as expected in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I have an excel with 10 columns, I need to validate the values in each column of this excel separately and that is why I am looping through each 
column one by one.

Now the validation for each column is different.For some columns I need to compare the values in the columns with the values in certain lists.

These Lists say:
List1
List2
List3...

Contain the Valid values.The values entered in the columns should be a part of these lists. So, say the first column
should contain only the values that are a part of list 1.

What could be the most efficient way to do this?
colcount here is 10, rowcount is 5.

```
for (int c = 1; c <= colcount; c++)
{
    for (int r = 2; r <= rowcount; r++) 
    {
        string celldata = usedRange.Cells[r,c].Text;
        if (c == 1)
        {
            if (List1.Contains(celldata))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (c == 2)
        {
            if (List2.Contains(celldata))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (c == 3)
        {
            if (List3.Length <=10 && regex.IsMatch(celldata))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can't figure out if I am making some basic mistake.

Comment: `return` will exit the entire function.What are you trying to accomplish by returning true and false?

Comment: In addition to what @DetectivePikachu said, your `for` loop smells of bad design. Once inside the inner loop you already know the value of `c`, so I think this could be restructured better.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you want your code to do, and what the structure of your objects are, to the extent that one can reproduce the situation.

Comment: Hi, @HereticMonkey I have edited the question. I hope this is fine

Comment: Hi @Sach I am new to this, if you could please tell me how can I make this efficient

Comment: You still haven't said what needs to happen if those lists contain the information, and when they don't. Currently you do `return true` and `return false` which abruptly _exists_ the function. You need to tell us what you need to happen in those situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get out of the inner loop use `break`.

> The break statement terminates the closest enclosing loop or switch statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break